# VB.net SDF file slow to update

Tags: vb.net, dataset, sql-server-ce

OK VB.net gurus. Riddle me this. I am beginning to use the little application I described in an earlier post. Updating the SDF file from a data table is pathetically slow. It is only very slow for a few hundred records. I updated the SDF file from a table of about 3,000 records and it took 8.5 minutes. In other words about the speed that a good fast typist could achieve doing data entry from the keyboard.  I have tried to upload a table with 100,000 records several times without success.
I am using a machine with a fast quad-core processor, 64 bit Win7, and 8 gigs of RAM. So processor speed and available RAM should not be an issue. The resulting table should be less than 100 Megs so the size limit on an SDF file should not be an issue either.
The issue seems to be the row by row updating process. In my research I have not found an alternative.

Comment: Who knows?  You need to profile your application.  Your method is not optimized at all (loading everything into a data table then writing that to a database -- ugh), but should work fast enough.  You could have memory or disk issues on that machine that could be balking at your inefficiency.

Comment: Lets see some code. Maybe you are opening a connection, executing an update, then closing the connection 3000 times in a loop.

Comment: You can use my SqlCeBulkCopy library to load a DataTable into SQL CE very quickly

Comment: thank you for your comments so far. I am currently using a data factory to load an SDF table from a stand alone dataset. This loads a local copy of the SDF table and then uses the AcceptChanges method to move the data to the SDF file. It chokes on a large rowset and I am looking for an alternative. I am about to punt returning to using as ADO.net insert command instead.